# Page not Found when I add jpeg on the filter plupload

Tags: plupload

I am using plupload version: **2.1.8** and every browser works fine on my PC.

When I want to upload a picture on my website from a IPhone 6s plus, I get the **extension error 601**.

If I add jpeg on my script the page will not load and I get page not found? Can someone help me?

This is my script for now before I add jpeg:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
    browse_button : 'pickfiles',
    container: document.getElementById('container'),
    url : '<?php echo WEBSITE_CNST_URL?>/upload.inc.php?adid=<?php echo $adid ?>',
    resize : { width : 1024, height : 768, quality : 80 },   


    flash_swf_url : '<?php echo WEBSITE_URL ?>/js/Moxie.swf',
    silverlight_xap_url : '<?php echo WEBSITE_URL ?>/js/Moxie.xap',

    filters : {
        max_file_size : '4mb',
        mime_types: [
            {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"}
        ]
    },
```

What is going wrong?